# BigQuery Count Unique and Count Distinct

Tags: google-bigquery, count, unique

I am looking for SQL to count unique values in the column.

I am aware of DISTINCT - that gives me how many unique values there are. However, I am looking for - how many **ONLY unique** values there are.

So if my data is Letters: {A,A,A,B,B,B,C,D}. I am looking to get:

```
Count Distinct = 4 {A,B,C,D) and
Count Unique = 2 {C,D} <== this is what I am looking for
```

I am working with BigQuery.

Thank You,
Do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below query will return **only unique** values in the column.

```sql
SELECT col
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('A,A,A,B,B,B,C,D')) col
 GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

[image]

Then, you can simply count rows.

```sql
WITH uniques AS (
  SELECT col
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('A,A,A,B,B,B,C,D')) col
   GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM uniques;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
select count(*) from (
  select * from your_table
  qualify 1 = count(*) over(partition by col)
)
```